# Equivalent of Type Spread from Flow in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, flowtype

In Flow we can do this:

```
type Props<T> = {
  ...T,
  other: string,
}
```

Is there an equivalent inside typescript? I'm trying to convert my code to typescript, but some basic stuff like this is giving quite the headache. Couldn't find anything related to this anywhere.

Comment: You mean, apart from [intersections](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types)?

Comment: If you really need spread as opposed to intersection (that is, you want to *overwrite* any colliding properties from `T`) you have to [build it yourself](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13288#issuecomment-412230721) with mapped and conditional types.

Comment: Thanks. That was it!

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you're asking for but perhaps you simply mean extending?

```
interface A {
  foo: string;
}
interface B extends A {
  bar: number;
}

const x: B = {
  foo: "some",
  bar: 10
};
```